# Efficient way to transform dict values

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

As an example, suppose I'm calculating an average of some variable within some categories.
One way to implement this calculation is the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

avg = defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])
for cat_name, val in data:
    cat = avg[cat_name]
    cat[0] += 1
    cat[1] += val

avg = { cat: s/n for cat,(n,s) in avg.items() }
```

This requires creating a new dictionary from the original one.

Alternatively, the division can be done in a loop like this:

```
for cat,(n,s) in avg.items():
    avg[cat] = s/n
```

This doesn't create a new dictionary object, but requires a key lookup on every iteration, which has the same complexity.

The thing is, the structure of the dictionary doesn't need to be changed, so no hash table lookup are actually necessary. The old values could just be substituted for the new ones in place. But is this possible to do in python?

In C++20, one can do something along these lines:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::variant<std::tuple<unsigned,double>,double>> avg;
// loop over data to accumulate counts and sums
for (auto& [cat,x] : avg) {
  auto [n,s] = x.get<0>();
  x = s/n;
}
```

which transforms the dictionary values in-place.

Is there a way to do something like that in python?

---

**Addendum**:
I only used the problem of calculating the averages as a concrete example. The question is about efficient transformation of the dictionary values.

While a `list` can be used to emulate a reference type, the solution I was thinking about would be along the lines of getting mutable access to the underlying storage of the dict object. Something like the `items()` method, but that returns something mutable instead of `tuple`s. Or maybe a function that takes a `dict` and a callback function that is used to transform the values, a la `map`, but in-place. In case the prose is not clear, something of this sort:

```
for x in dict_instance.mutable_items():
    x.value = x.value[1]/x.value[0]
```

or

```
dict_instance.transform_values(lambda v: v[1]/v[0])
```

---

**Addendum 2**:
I also realize that I could just change the meaning of one of the original list elements, say from sum to average, by doing this:

```
for val in avg.values():
    val[1] = val[1]/val[0]
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to replace the whole value object and avoid lookup.

Comment: No, I don't think there's a way to replace a dictionary value in place without doing the lookup. But dictionary lookups are cheap.

Comment: no matter the solution you will need to lookup the key in order to set a new value, because `dict.__setitem__(self, key, value, /)` requires both the key and value

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use list trick.

```
from collections import defaultdict
# You use list object for average
avg = defaultdict(lambda:[0,0, list([0])])
for cat_name, val in data:
    cat = avg[cat_name]
    cat[0] += 1
    cat[1] += val

for _, (s, n, lst) in avg.items():
    lst[0] = s / n
```

The solution doesn't require a key lookup, but it increases the memory usage.

Or

If total of val variable is only use averaging process, you can use incremental mean.

Incremental Mean Formula from David Silver's lecture slide
[image]

Comment: Both suggestions are interesting and have a place in this discussion for the
sake of completeness. +1. The drawback of the list trick is the introduction of
storage indirection. But it spiritually gets the closest to the root of the
problem, in that python lacks a reference type. The drawback of the running
average method is that it requires a division and an extra subtraction on every
iteration besides the addition, and only circumvents the example problem, but
doesn't solve the problem of transformation of the dictionary values. Also, see
the addendum to the question.